# SQL Max or empty value grouped by conditions

Tags: sql, scripting

I have a table like this
[image]

and i want my output to look like this

[image]

I need to look at the ID and then take max created date and max completed date for that ID. There is also some cases where completed date is still empty so in that case i just need to look at the max created date. Im not sure how to tackle this, doing a group by doesnt account for my multiple scenarios

Comment: What is your actual SQL _database_ (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle) ?

Comment: sql data base is sql server

Comment: As explained in the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please do not post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of code or data. We cannot copy or use data from a picture.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY QUOTE_NUMBER
                                 ORDER BY WORKBOOK_CREATED_DATE DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE rn = 1;
```